# authentication system requirements for a stand alone web app

Tags: authentication, web-applications, authorization

What should my authentication requirements be for a stand alone web application that will not integrate with any other applications?  I know that I will need to have the following features, but am I missing anything?

- unattended password reset
- lock account after multiple failed login attempts
- roles for different kinds of users
- log all login attempts
- integrate with htaccess file and deny authorization to a given directory if login attempt is not successful

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Other than configuring the firewall to ban a users IP after multiple failed login attempts to prevent brute force attacks **and** 
enforce password management *(apply basic password management rules, such as password length, history, complexity and mandate that all users change their passwords regularly)* your lists seems quite solid.